# Measure performance and time used by Python web server

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, bottle

I'm running a website using [Bottle](http://www.bottlepy.org) and Sqlite, which are both lightweight, on a small private hosting (using Linux).
I'm starting to have more and more users each day.

How to measure if both of them are :

- running smoothly, using only < 10% of CPU / RAM of the hosting computer
- running with a medium usage, this is a premature sign meaning I should think about using something more production-ready for multi-users than Sqlite
- running with a very high CPU or RAM usage, meaning that a pipe is going to break soon ... if I don't modify something !

Answer (score 0):

To simply measure CPU and memory use, you can log into the machine and run `top` or `htop`.

I assume, though, that you don't simply want to measure, but that you also want **monitoring** and **alerts**. In that case you'll need to run some sort of monitoring framework; which one to choose is a broader question. One popular choice that you might take a look at is [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/).